# How to group two items with two dates and get durations in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I usually work with data look like this `{'id': '1', 'start_date': '2012-04-8', 'end_date': '2012-08-06'}` but now I have something very different. I have  items of items where each two-element represents the one item

```
    data = [
    {'id': '1', 'field': 'end_tmie', 'value': '2012-08-06'},
    {'id': '1', 'field': 'start_date', 'value': '2012-04-8'},
    {'id': '2', 'field': 'end_tmie', 'value': '2012-01-06'},
    {'id': '2', 'field': 'start_date', 'value': '2012-03-8'},
    ]
```

- **Goal** how to get the duration `end_time -start_time` for each two data points with the same id in `pandas`
- **data Goal**

```
       df = [
        {'id': '1', 'durations': '2012-08-06 - 2012-04-8'},
        {'id': '2', 'durations': '2012-01-06 - 2012-03-8'},
       ]
```

- **2 data Goal** how to resample data to look like tihs

```
    df = [
    {'id':'1', 'start':'2012-04-8', 'end':'2012-08-06'},
    {'id':'2', 'start':'2012-03-8', 'end':'2012-01-06'},

    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create DataFrame constructor first, then [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with rename columns and for duration convert subtract columns with convert timedetas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['value'] = pd.to_datetime(df['value'])
df = df.pivot(index='id',columns='field',values='value').rename(columns={'start_date':'start','end_tmie':'end'})
df['durations'] = df['end'].sub(df['start']).dt.days
```

Last for exports filter columns with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d1 = df['durations'].reset_index().to_dict('records')
print (d1)
[{'id': '1', 'durations': 120}, {'id': '2', 'durations': -62}]

d2 = df[['start','end']].apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).reset_index().to_dict('records')
print (d2)
[{'id': '1', 'start': '2012-04-08', 'end': '2012-08-06'},
 {'id': '2', 'start': '2012-03-08', 'end': '2012-01-06'}]
```

Comment: when it cames to the real data I got too many errors can you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848726/how-to-get-the-list-of-durations-of-any-two-elements-with-common-field-value)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are no multiple value of `start_date` and `end_tmie` for each `id`, `pd.pivot_table()` should do the job.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [
...     {'id': '1', 'field': 'end_tmie', 'value': '2012-08-06'},
...     {'id': '1', 'field': 'start_date', 'value': '2012-04-8'},
...     {'id': '2', 'field': 'end_tmie', 'value': '2012-01-06'},
...     {'id': '2', 'field': 'start_date', 'value': '2012-03-8'},
... ]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df.pivot_table('value', 'id', 'field', lambda x: x).sort_index(ascending=False, axis=1).assign(duration=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['end_tmie']) - pd.to_datetime(x['start_date']))
field start_date    end_tmie duration
id
1      2012-04-8  2012-08-06 120 days
2      2012-03-8  2012-01-06 -62 days
```